# serverless functions accepting the usage of Port 25

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-functions, smtp, cloud, tls1.2

A simple question today :)

Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked in both AWS lambdas and google cloud functions.
I would love to know if somebody knows any alternative.

I understand they are blocked to avoid spam but I'm actually just willing to ping the smtp server to check if the email address I'm sending an email too exists before sending the actual email.

I have some alternatives in mind:

- Find some cloud functions that accept it?
- Kind of route my pings trougth a vpn or something similar?
- Using port 587 or 465  => But i have no idea how to do that

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  If you are looking to check on a remote SMTP server to see if a given email address is valid - don't bother.  Most accept any email address initially and reject later.  This is to prevent real-time address harvesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP ports are blocked for Cloud Functions however there are some workarounds that you can use:

1 - Using a third party service like [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) which offers free 12,000 transactional emails each month to free trial users. There are similar service such as [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun), [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet).

2 - You can take advantage of using [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_sendgrid_to_send_emails) to send emails using port 25. The Cloud Function can send the email content and details to an endpoint of a running application inside your VM and then you can simple send the email from your GCE instance.